# Is normal MySql index required when we have Composite index

Tags: mysql, sql

We have MySql table having 25 million rows

Following are the columns in table

```
c_id,c_name,s_id,l_type,l_time,message,domain
```

among above we have normal indexes on c_id,c_name,s_id,l_type,domain columns

I'm planning to add composite index on domain, l_time, l_type columns. So now can I remove individual index on domain?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any prefix of a composite index will be used as an index by itself as well. So if you have a composite index on `(domain, log_time, log_type)`, it's equivalent to having indexes on `domain` and `(domain, log_time)`. There's no need to have these indexes separately as well, they will be redundant and waste space.

So you can safely remove the index on `domain` when you add this composite index.

Answer (score 0):

It is not compulsory to remove individual index for adding composite index, based on requirement either you can keep or drop it/them.